# brain.js: XOR example does not work

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to understand [brain.js](https://github.com/harthur/brain).

This is my code; it does not work. (Explaination of what I *expect* it to do below)

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/harthur/brain/gh-pages/brain-0.6.3.min.js">

<script>
var net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

net.train([{input: [0, 0], output: [0]},
           {input: [0, 1], output: [1]},
           {input: [1, 0], output: [1]},
           {input: [1, 1], output: [0]}]);

var output = net.run([1, 0]);
document.write(output[1]);
</script>
```

This code imports the brain.min.js code and then teaches a neural network how to do the [XOR operation](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

I expect it to return 0.978 (or somewhere around that), but I'm staring at a blank HTML page. I hope someone who's feeling helpful points me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: just saw that this is your first post. Welcome to stackoverflow. If you got your answer, please remember to accept the answer. That way everybody can see, that the problem is solved and which answer did the job.

Comment: @jhinzmann i'll do that as soon as I have checked that your answer works. thanks for the welcome, btw :)

Comment: are there still any problems with my answer?

Comment: @jhinzmann I don't think so – just haven't had time to test.

Comment: why do you accept my answer and unaccept it a month later with no edits or comments to your question or my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in JavaScript are zero based.

Therefore you have to use `document.write(output[0]);`.

Maybe it would be helpfull to use a [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Console/log) or even better a `debugger;` statement. This way you can inspect your variables through the JS Console.

More info on debugging can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp).

Answer (score 0):

This code works in 2019:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/brain.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork({hiddenLayers: [3]});

    net.train([{input: [0, 0], output: [0]},
        {input: [0, 1], output: [1]},
        {input: [1, 0], output: [1]},
        {input: [1, 1], output: [0]}]);

    const output = net.run([0, 1]);
    document.write(output[0])
</script>
</body>
</html>
```